# How to vectorize vector-matrix element-by-element operation?

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
A = rand(N1,N2);
b = rand(1,N1);
B = zeros(N1,N2);

for i=1:N1
   for j=1:N2
      B(i,j) = A(i,j)*b(i);
   end   
end
```

The question is how to write it in vector operation form?  Something like `B(:,:) = A(:,:).*b(:)`.

Comment: since all variables are zeros, what's the point ? just `B = zeros(N1,N2);` is enough

Comment: Your inner loop is trivially removed. Vectorizing the outer loop cleanly is something that Octave supports but MATLAB doesn't, though as answered below, `bsxfun` may be faster than a single explicit loop, and certainly should be faster than the nested explicit loops you've shown above.

Comment: @natan I'm pretty sure that the OP put those in there simply to illustrate the dimensions.  You surely gotta have *some* faith in a person!!

Comment: paddy, believe me, with the things I've seen here in the past year  nothing will surprise me...

Comment: @natan, actually, all variables are not zeros. The problem is how to eliminate loops and not how to multiply zeros.

Comment: so why don't you write `A = rand(N1,N2);` etc?

Comment: @natan Good point, I have taken the liberty of editing `rand` into the question.

Answer (score 7):

Simple use for `bsxfun`:

```
B = bsxfun(@times, A, b')
```

Comment: Yes, `bsxfun` will utterly smite your petty nested for-loops. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
B = A*.(repmat(b,N2,1))';
```

Here, firstly you produce `N2` repeated version of vector `b` and multiply it with `A` in an elementwise manner